# Very Simple Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been asked if there is a better way to write this query and I can think of none. Please help:

```
 select bookid, bookname
   from books
  where bookname not like 'D%' or bookname not like 'F%'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT bookid,
       bookname
FROM   books
WHERE  bookname IS NOT NULL
```

Maintains the semantics of your original query.  Perhaps you meant to use `AND` instead of `OR`

```
SELECT bookid,
       bookname
FROM   books
WHERE  bookname NOT LIKE '[DF]%'
```